# encode html in Asp.net C# but leave tags intact

Tags: c#, html-encode

I need to encode a whole text while leaving the < and > intact.

example

```
<p>Give me 100.000 €!</p>
```

must become:

```
<p>Give me 100.000 &euro;!</p>
```

the html tags must remain intact

Comment: Do you absolutely need to encode those values or can you just output everything as unicode? If you really need to encode the text then I'd probably say that you're going to have to go through the Html Agility Pack. But remember, € is a valid unicode character if you set the MIME type correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression that matches either a tag or what's between tags, and encode what's between:

```
html = Regex.Replace(
  html,
  "(<[^>]+>|[^<]+)",
  m => m.Value.StartsWith("<") ? m.Value : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(m.Value)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

you might go for [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and then encode the values of the tags

Comment: +1 - I think this solves most of the issues with trying to do it with replace or regex, and it's probably less work than creating your own whitelist of tags to ignore or characters to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use string.replace for just those characters you want to encode?

Comment: This has to be the best approach. It looks like the OP is trying to encode non-ASCII entities (probably to get around character set issues). For that, a regex matching >127 and replacing with known entity names would be best. Or better yet, sorting out he charset issue if that's the underlying problem. :-)

Comment: or the other way around. First encode everything and the &lt; en &gt; back to < and >

Answer (score 0):

You could use HtmlTextWriter in addition to htmlencode.  So you would use HtmlTextWriter to setup your `<p></p>` and then just set the body of the `<p></p>` using HtmlEncode.  HtmlTextWriter allow ToString(); and a bunch of other methods so it shouldn't be much more code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, this can be achieved with [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/).

```
 public static class HtmlTextEncoder
 {
    public static string HtmlEncode(string html)
    {
        if (html == null) return null;

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        EncodeNode(doc.DocumentNode);

        doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
        using (var s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            doc.Save(s);
            var encoded = doc.Encoding.GetString(s.ToArray());
            return encoded;
        }
    }

    private static void EncodeNode(HtmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    childNode.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(childNode.InnerHtml);
                }
                else
                {
                    EncodeNode(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            node.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(node.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates through all the nodes in the HTML, and replaces any text nodes with HTML encoded text.

I've created a [.NET fiddle to demonstrate this technique](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YQZFQj).