# Better way to encode all less than (<) characters in a HTML string, but not the HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, string, html-encode

I am cleaning a HTML string to encode the less than sign (<) to a HTML entity (`&lt;`), but leaving the HTML tags as they are. An example is converting `"<div>Total < 500</div>"` to `"<div>Total &lt; 500</div>"`.

There's a number of posts addressing this including:
[html entity encode text only, not html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464686/html-entity-encode-text-only-not-html-tag), [encode html in Asp.net C# but leave tags intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245066/encode-html-in-asp-net-c-sharp-but-leave-tags-intact), [How to encode special characters in HTML but exclude tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301206/how-to-encode-special-characters-in-html-but-exclude-tags)
Each post points to using the Html Agility Pack and specifically the `HtmlEntity.Entitize(html)` method. This doesn't work for me because it actually ignores the < and & signs and using the above example, the output was the same as the input! I may be missing the point of how to use this method, but the code was simply this:

```
public static string EntitizeHtml( this string html )
{
   return HtmlEntity.Entitize( html );
}
```

I decided to write my own method to find the less than symbols and convert them to the HTML entity equivalent. It works, but it seems very clunky (a loop inside a loop and lots of string manipulation). I avoided Regex to keep it faster and more readable. I fully appreciate that manipulating HTML strings is often fraught with problems thanks to differing HTML versions and malformed HTML, but for my purpose this method solves my problem based on a discrete set of HTML tags. The following method will convert `"<div>Total < 500</div>"` to `"<div>Total &lt; 500</div>"` as expected.

If anyone can improve the efficiency of this method I'd be very grateful.

```
        public static string EncodeLessThanEntities( this string html )
        {
            if( !html.Contains( "<" ) )
            {
                return html;
            }

            // get the full html length
            int length = html.Length;
            // set a limit on the tag string to compare to reduce the 
            // string size (i.e. the longest tags are <center> and <strong>)
            int tagLength = 6;
            // gather all the included html tags to check
            string s = "div|span|p|br|ol|ul|li|center|font|strong|em|sub|sup";
            string[] tags = s.Split( '|' ).ToArray( );
            // find all the indices of the less than entity or tag
            var indices = AllIndexesOf( html, "<" );
            // initiate a list of indices to be replaced
            var replaceable = new List<int>( );

            // loop through the indices
            foreach( var index in indices )
            {
                // store the potential tag (up to the tag length)
                if( length - ( index + 1 ) < tagLength ) tagLength = length - ( index + 1 );
                string possibleTag = html.Substring( index + 1, tagLength );
                // automatically ignore any closing tags
                if( possibleTag.Substring( 0, 1 ) == "/" )
                {
                    continue;
                }

                bool match = false;

                // loop through each html tag to find a match
                foreach( var tag in tags )
                {
                    if( possibleTag.StartsWith( tag ) )
                    {
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if( !match )
                {
                    // if there is no match to a html tag, store the index
                    replaceable.Add( index );
                }
            }

            if( replaceable?.Any( ) ?? false )
            {
                // loop through each index and replace the '<' with '&lt;'
                foreach( var index in Enumerable.Reverse( replaceable ) )
                {
                    html = html.ReplaceAt( index, 1, "&lt;" );
                }
            }

            return html;
        }


        public static List<int> AllIndexesOf( this string input, string value )
        {
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>( );

            if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) )
            {
                return indexes;
            }

            for( int index = 0; ; index += value.Length )
            {
                index = input.IndexOf( value, index );
                if( index == -1 )
                {
                    return indexes;
                }
                indexes.Add( index );
            }
        }


        public static string ReplaceAt( this string str, int index, int length, string replace )
        {
            return str.Remove( index, Math.Min( length, str.Length - index ) ).Insert( index, replace );
        }
```

I'm hoping there is a way to make the above method more efficient. Or maybe this is as good as it gets? I know there are a lot of very smart guys out there with a lot more experience and I don't include myself in that group!

Comment: Probably better for codereview.stackexchange.com because the code does work. However, in general, I'd say it's a very bad idea to do HTML sanitation yourself. I would highly recommend using a library for this. There are many that properly parse the HTML and then escape the `<`s.

Comment: Thanks @Sumner Evans. I posted this on codereview.stackexchange.com so hopefully this will help. I would have preferred to use HtmlAgility, but it did not work for me despite a lot of research. Maybe I'm missing something, but my requirements are fairly simple so it's a bit odd.